# checkboxes checked by default in knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I have created a jsfiddle with my code: http://jsfiddle.net/hw7c9b76/ but it doesnt really display the problem unfortunately because the data is not persistent.

When I have a few entries in the database, and I reload, the checkboxes are all checked and the fields that should be hidden are displayed, even though the editable property is set to false.

Is there a way to be sure that the fields are hidden and the buttons unchecked on load?

Here is the html, because stackoverflow doesnt let me just post a jsfiddle link without code being included:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Knockout experiment</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form data-bind="submit: addFriend">
        Add Friend: <input data-bind="value: newFriendNameText" placeholder="Name" /> <input data-bind="value: newFriendAgeText" placeholder="Age" />
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: friends">
        <li>
            <span data-bind="text:name"></span> 
            <span data-bind="text:age"></span>
            <input data-bind="visible: editable, textInput: name" />
            <input data-bind="visible: editable, textInput: age" />
            <a href="#" data-bind="visible: editable, click: $parent.updateFriend">Save Edits</a>
            <input type="checkbox" value="edit" data-bind="checked:editable">Make Edits</a>
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeFriend">Delete</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
    <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
    <script src="knockout-mapping.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Look in the console when you reload, are there any binding errors? Sometimes this can happen and then it prevents further bindings down the page from working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data from your service is inconsistent. Inconsistency is while returning editable's value

Data from Service

```
friends = [{"name":"aaad","age":"30","editable":"false","id":1},
               {"name":"ffff","age":"4","editable":"false","id":2},
               {"name":"werw","age":"3","editable":"false","id":3}];
```

And data Should be

```
friends = [{"name":"aaad","age":"30","editable":false,"id":1},
           {"name":"ffff","age":"4","editable":false,"id":2},
           {"name":"werw","age":"3","editable":false,"id":3}];
```

Look at this JS fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Dnyanesh/k96tzdbz/ (I have copied your code and made some chnages)
This fiddle is working as expected.

Now what is root cause value for editable when it is will be other than `false` will be considered as true. Because there is no type safety in javascript your value "false" is also getting considered and editable is getting set to true.

If you do not have control over what data is coming form services used you can set eiditable value as false always. I have updated fiddle with following change. http://jsfiddle.net/Dnyanesh/k96tzdbz/1/

```
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(friends, function(fr){
           var frdCls = new FriendClass(fr)
            self.friends.push(frdCls);
        });
```

In this case no matter data come from service it will be set to false.

Comment: So the service does not have a field for editable, but is there a way that I could set editable to false on all of these in the model on load?

Comment: I am not saying 'does not have a field for editable'. I am saying if data for editable field come like "editable":false instead of "editable":"false" you job will get done. If that is out of control as data is coming from rd party then need to think of some other way.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I notice that the calls to the mapping plugin are commented out, yet is still works as expected. Does this assignment of each fr as an instance of the FriendClass do the same thing as the mapping plugin?

Comment: Yes correct var frdCls = new FriendClass(fr) line from arrayForEach will create new object which will have this.editable = false always.